# String variable with quotes in powershell

Tags: powershell, winscp

I need to run winscp.com with some parameters within a powershell script. 
If I do the following in the console, it works as expected.

```
Set-Alias WINSCP "C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\WinSCP.com"
WINSCP /command "option batch continue" "option confirm off" "option reconnecttime 5" "open username:Password@SFTPServer -privatekey=\\server\share\Private_Key.ppk" "mkdir /folder/subfolder" "exit"
```

I need to store this command as a variable, as it will be generated automatically based on the requirements. So i did as below:

```
Set-Alias WINSCP "C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\WinSCP.com"
$comm = "`"option batch continue`" `"option confirm off`" `"option reconnecttime 5`" `"open username" + ":password@SFTPServer -privatekey=\\server\share\privatekey.ppk`" `"mkdir /folder/subfolder`" `"exit`"" 
WINSCP /command $comm
```

However, this seems not to be working. Somewhere the string parsing is messed up. When I run this script, it will prompt for the SFTP server name. It supposed to parse it from the command provided earlier. The output is like below:

```
PS C:\> Set-Alias WINSCP "C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\WinSCP.com"
PS C:\> $comm = "`"option batch continue`" `"option confirm off`" `"option reconnecttime 5`" `"open username" + ":password@SFTPServer -privatekey=\\server\share\privatekey.ppk`" `"mkdir /folde
r/subfolder`" `"exit`""
PS C:\> WINSCP /command $comm
Opening session using command-line parameter in scripting is deprecated. Use 'open' command instead.
Host:
```

But if I print the `$comm` variable, it seems to be correct.

```
"option batch continue" "option confirm off" "option reconnecttime 5" "open username:password@SFTPServer -privatekey=\\server\share\privatekey.ppk" "mkdir /folder/subfolder" "exit"
```

What is wrong here ?

UPDATE : **This seems to be an issue with PowerShell 5.1**
I ran the same script in `Windows Server 2008 R2` with `PowerShell 2.0`, `Windows Server 2012 R2` with `Powershell 3.0`, and `Windows Server 2016` and `Windows 10` with `PowerShell 5.1`. Those with 5.1 fails, while other two works. Screenshots below:

[image: PowerShell 2.0]
[image: PowerShell 3.0]
[image: PowerShell 5.1]

Comment: Why don't you just use the WINSCP .NET library in your script instead of making calls to its external executable?  It's much more robust that way and they even have documentation for how to use it in PowerShell on their website (also the application itself has a "Convert to PowerShell" option)

Comment: I ve never tried that before, but is there any external dependencies to be installed ? Like libraries ? This is supposed to run on a very restrictive environment where additional installations are really difficult to get approved.

Comment: No, your script will just need the dll deployed with it (or it's probably already included in your WinSCP path).  [Here's the relevant documentation link](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_powershell)

Comment: one possible solution is to build a string array of the parameters and then use that as the argument list for the external app. for instance, robocopy will accept a string array like this `robocopy $RC_Params`.

Answer (score 1):

```
$comm = "`"option batch continue`" `"option confirm off`" `"option reconnecttime 5`" `"open username" + ":password@SFTPServer -privatekey=\\server\share\privatekey.ppk`" `"mkdir /folder/subfolder`" `"exit`"" 
WINSCP /command $comm
```

The above will pass `$comm` as **one** parameter to WinSCP, not as six parameters.

I believe it's very difficult to make PowerShell do what you really want, while keeping `$comm` a string variable.

But it's easy, if you change `$comm` to an array:

```
$comm = "option batch continue", "option confirm off", "option reconnecttime 5", "open username:password@SFTPServer -privatekey=\\server\share\privatekey.ppk", "mkdir /folder/subfolder", "exit"
```

If you need to keep `$comm` as a string for configuration purposes, use your own unique separator (I use pipe `|` here):

```
$comm = "option batch continue|option confirm off|option reconnecttime 5|open username:password@SFTPServer -privatekey=\\server\share\privatekey.ppk|mkdir /folder/subfolder|exit" 
WINSCP /log=log.log /command $comm.split("|")
```

---

In general it's better to use [WinSCP .NET assembly in PowerShell](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_powershell), rather then scripting interface. But I understand that you have your specific reasons in this case.

Comment: My method actually works in older powershell versions. I updated the question. But in the current version,  I will try to use this method and will update again

Answer (score 1):

I suggest passing your arguments as an array and splatting so everything is joined/passed properly:

```
$winscp = "${Env:ProgramFiles(x86)}\WinSCP\WinSCP.com"
$winscpArgs = @(
    '/command'
    '"option batch continue"'
    '"option confirm off"'
    '"option reconnecttime 5"'
    '"open username:password@SFTPServer -privatekey=\\server\share\privatekey.ppk"'
    '"mkdir /folder/subfolder"'
    '"exit"'
)
& $winScp @winscpArgs
```

The better option, however, is using the library provided by WinSCP (TODO).